# How to run tomcat as root user - and why tomcat usuallu run under own user?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Good day,

I try to configure Hippo cms (tomcat-based application) to run on our own test/dev server.

I follow Hippo's manual page https://www.onehippo.org/library/enterprise/installation-and-configuration/linux-installation-manual.html and on our sandbox server, which is ubuntu, everything works out of the box as described - great! As per manual, I run tomcat as a cms user. The manual prescribes to install tomcat under /usr/local/tomcat, then  create a new user, "cms" with home folder in /opt/cms and to create secondary tomcat configuration in there, under "tomcat" folder just to run and instance of Tomcat specific for Hippo cms. Tomcat runs in /opt/cms/tomcat directory.

Now, we use vargant in dev, and that is uses RedHat, and all the processes should run as root (company rule). I follow the same manual to the letter, installing tomcat in /usr/loca/ and configure secondary tomcat to run in /opt/cms/tomcat as per manual, except this time I don't create a new user - the folder is owned by root.
I use the same /etc/init.d/cms script to start services in both cases, however on RHL tomcat starts from /usr/local/tomcat and it doesn't pick up Hippo webapps that are deployed under /opt/cms/tomcat.

I know it's difficult to diagnose the proble from such a sketchy description alone, but perhaps someone could help me with the following mysteries:

1. Why is it always recommended to run tomcat under its own user?
2. How to configure tomcat to run under root user and know what the trick is to make tomcat run as root?

Many thanks,
Nestor

Comment: Company rule to run everything as root? Does company also mandate that every password must be "password"?

Comment: oh Kayaman, there are sysadmins and there are sysadmins, you know...

Comment: 'password' much to insecure! We use passw0rd. Much better!

Comment: `p@55w0Rd` is much more secure, [we all know that!](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: Hey admins, come on. This question has been viewed 2500 times - folks finds it really useful. Surely we can re-open it for the benefit of the community?

Comment: Sidenote: if you decide to NOT install Tomcat as root, but, let's say "tomcat", you can run: # useradd tomcat # passwd tomcat # usermod -aG sudo tomcat . Then give a shell to the tomcat user in "/etc/passwd" : replace "/bin/false" by "/bin/bash" in the tomcat line. Then log in as "tomcat" : # su tomcat. Then proceed with the installation steps as User tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why is it always recommended to run tomcat under its own user?

Because security best practices, every web app running on that instance would have access to **every** part of the system and could do **everything** they wanted.

The most basic security flaw could let everything run `rm -rf /`. *Think about this, then ask yourself if you really want an answer to #2?*

> 2. How to configure tomcat to run under root user and know what the trick is to make tomcat run as root?

Don't try and do this because of #1.

Comment: i want tomcat to write log files right.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the second part of your question:

Assume that you are a landlord, renting apartments in your house. Do you hand the people who rent a room ... the key to their individual room; or do you give everybody the master key that opens all doors?!

That is why the normal policy is to run as few things as possible as **root**. Because **root** can do **anything** on your systems. In other words: when somebody manages to break out of tomcat ... then he already has root privileges. If tomcat runs as some non-root user; the intruder still has more hurdles to overcome; even when he manages to break out of tomcat.

But I guess your company policy to run things as root is about internal **development** that are not connected to the internet?! Anything else would be a "strange" policy.

In case you don't get good answers on your first question; my recommendation: hippo has its own [forum](https://www.onehippo.org/about/community/cms-forums.html); I am pretty sure that asking your question there has higher chances of receiving helpful, technically correct responses.

Comment: *the key to their individual room; or do you give everybody the master key that opens all doors?!*, your bank accounts, everyone elses bank accounts in the building, all your and everyone in the places usernames and passwords, etc. **Can do anything** actually more accurately means **Can do everything**.

Comment: Thank you GhostCat. Yeah that's a dev we're talking about.  I've also asked on Hippo forum. Will let everyone know if I get an answer...

Comment: Well, hopefully not passwords. They should not be stored on any system. But who knows maybe they have a policy for that too.